# Cassandra store timestamps as strings

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cqlsh

I know that Cassandra has a timestamp data type. I'm using it but I'm having some troubles with it (time zones in particular). My question is, which are (if they exist) the drawbacks of using a string where to store '2014-05-09 14:12:00' instead of the timestamp type?

I already tried using the operators >, >=, <=, < and everything works fine.

Thank you

Comment: Why would the time zones be a problem?

Comment: Have no idea, I'm not able to figure out what the problem is but everything is inserted with +1hour if loaded during the winter time while everything works fine during the summer time. Of course, this difference creates a lot of trouble when querying.

Comment: @MauricePerry, The problem would be with daylight saving Time. If I store a timestamp with time zone offet in winter, the timestamp is stored as UTC, if I query the same record in summer, and convert it from UTC to local time, the result would have a difference equals to the daylight saving time offset.

Comment: @RADU the offset to use when retrieving depends on the timestamp you're retrieving, not on the current date/time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the timezone unless you want to format the date. If you store a formatted date instead of a timestamp, if will only be correct in the timezone for which it was formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra timestamp type is stored as a long value (time since epoch), which allows range queries (<,<=, >, >=). Those can not be executed on a string type. Only = and in queries are supported.